# Promise in a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have been trying to add promise into a function, I have this error TypeError: sort_devices_name.then is not a function, function get_groups_devices is calling sort_devices_name and sort_devices_name is the function that i want to use as the promise.

```
 });
                // Find devices object id with relation of groups
                get_groups_devices();
            }
        });

            function sort_devices_name() {
             return   new Promise(
                    function (resolve, reject) {
                        var d_ids = data.map(function (d) {
                            return ObjectId(d.d_id);
                        });
                        devices_lookup.find({"_id": {$in: d_ids}}).sort({"device_name": 1}).toArray(function (err, d_data) {
                            if (err) {
                                return res.send(JSON.stringify(err));
                            }
                            else {
                                var modify_data = [];
                                d_data.forEach(function (val) {
                                    data.forEach(function (val2) {
                                        if (val2.d_id == val._id) {
                                            modify_data.push({g_id: val2.g_id, d_id: val._id});
                                        }
                                    });
                                });
                                resolve(modify_data);
                            }
                        });
                    });
            }



        // Find devices object id with relation of groups (if any) from devices group relation table.
        function get_groups_devices() {
            devices_group.find({"g_id": {$in: groups_ids}}, {
                "d_id": 1,
                "g_id": 1,
                "_id": 0
            }).toArray(function (err, d_data) {
                d_data = sort_devices_name(d_data);
                sort_devices_name.then(function (d_data) {
                    console.log(d_data);
                    if (err) {
                        return res.send(JSON.stringify(err));
                    } else {
```

[image]

Comment: You do not call your function currently, but just access the function object, which itself has no `then()` method. call the function `sort_devices_name().then()`.

Comment: @Sirko Thanks, its working fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **call** `sort_devices_name`, not just refer to it; add `()`:

```
sort_devices_name().then(function...
// --------------^^
```

The *function* doesn't have a `then` property, but the promise it returns does.